# How do i get product category url and name on product detail page?

Tags: magento-1.9

How do i get product category url and name on product detail page?

```
<a href="<?php echo $helper->categoryAttribute($product, $product->getCategory(), 'url'); ?>">
    View All 
    <?php echo $helper->categoryAttribute($product, $product->getCategory(), 'name'); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code.

```
    <?php $cat_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); ?>
    <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id); ?>
    <?php echo $category->getName(); ?>
    <?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`

```
$_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');
<a href=<?php echo $_category_detail->getUrl();?>>View All <?php echo $_category_detail->getName();?></a>
```

`

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You can call the model from product ID

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

foreach ($categoryIds as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
    echo $_cat->getName(); 
    echo $_cat->getUrl();            
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the product is in multiple categories, as the question is about the *current* product detail page.

Comment: The foreach loop is there for it ? Why do you think it wont work ?